# Rename SQL Column Error : Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I wanted to rename my column.

I referred [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/26/sql-server-how-to-rename-a-column-name-or-table-name/) document.

I wrote a query as:

```
sp_RENAME '[dbo].[File].[JSONFile]', '[ARAInputJson]', 'COLUMN'
```

But now column is created as `[ARAInputJson]`

But I don't want to put square brackets to it.

So again I wrote it as :

```
sp_RENAME '[dbo].[File].[[ARAInputJson]]' , 'ARAInputJson', 'COLUMN'
```

But I get this error :

> Msg 15248, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 215
>   Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.

Please help me to rename column from `[ARAInputJson]` to `ARAInputJson`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should solve your square bracket issue:

```
sp_RENAME 'dbo.File."[ARAInputJson]"' , 'ARAInputJson', 'COLUMN'
```

Answer (score 2):

Well remove all those `[]` and try like

```
sp_RENAME 'dbo.File.[ARAInputJson]' , 'ARAInputJson', 'COLUMN'
```

Comment: this I had to done previously.. but by mistake I kept brackets :- 'dbo.File.[ARAInputJson]' , '[ARAInputJson]', 'COLUMN'

Comment: @CSharper, So does this works or you still receiving error?

Comment: no this does not work for me now becase its not getting column ARAInputJson as [ARAInputJson] column is there

Answer (score 2):

```
sp_RENAME '[dbo].[File].[[ARAInputJson]]]' , 'ARAInputJson', 'COLUMN'
```